# What sublime text 3 language works with json like code?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-3, json

Sublime Text 3 works great for editing, however it doesn't seem to have support for json like languages that use comments.

For example: [HCL (hashicorp language)](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl) is compatible with json, but also allows comments

```
{
  "foo":"bar"
   #here is a comment, can't do this in regular json
}
```

Another example is [logstash configs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#_structure_of_a_config_file)

```
input {
  stdin {codec => json}
}
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => [ "FOO", "foo" ]
  }
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug} }
```

I don't see any languages in sublime that support syntax highlighting with these types of documents. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `YAML` parser will provide syntax highlighting for Hashicorp Language (HCL) style code including logstash configs.

[image]